# How to ajust screen dynmically of unity game in android device?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]
Hi.

I have read about scaling-GUI and image aspect ratio, and even if it's a lot of scripts and tutorials out there it's hard to find a good way to handle it for so many different devices and screens.

But for my game it doesn't need to be so complicated, I hope. Scaling the 2D GUI was a quick fix making them a % of the value from Screen.width

The attached jpg shows the only problem I need to fix. The first picture shows the scene in a some kind of normal aspect ratio where i see the whole (test) scene. Pic 1 dragging the view sideways, and important game elements will disappear out of the screen (this is what I don't want). Pic 2 on the other hand showing that Unity scale the scene but so you see the whole scene no matter how extreme widescreen I make it.

And this is really what I want; make it scale the scene sideways and not crop it out of the picture.. Any idea how I make Unity do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty Gameobject and attach following script so everytime you run a game your screen will adjust

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScreenAdjust : MonoBehaviour {

```
void Start () {
    Camera.main.aspect = 800f/1280f;
}
```

}

Comment: I want to adjust on any screen

Comment: Camera.main.aspect = Screen.width / Screen.height; ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Canvas Scaler

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.CanvasScaler.html

Here is a short tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkfhxuNr9Es